# Atom/Sass-lint: Regex for sass-lint.yml class-name

Tags: regex, sass, atom-editor, scss-lint, sass-lint

I have a sass-lint.yml file with the following rule:

```
class-name-format:
    - 1
    - convention: '^([a-zA-Z]*)(__[a-z]+)?(-[a-z]*)*(--[a-z]+)?$'
```

The regex can be checked here:
https://regex101.com/r/SsVde6/2

Unfortunately I can't get it to work properly.

In the regex tester you see what kind of things I want to include.
The first part of the Class name can be PascalCase from then on BEMified ([BEM](http://getbem.com/)) kebabcase (e.g.: `this-is-kebab-case` – all lowercase with dashes in between)

A very common pattern would look like:
`ComponentName__element-name--modifier-name`

Quite a few things work already, but I would like to evaluate nested BEM selectors in my scss files as well:

`&__burgerCross {…}` or `&__burger_cross` or `&__burger__cross` for example should be evaluated as false. This would have to be `&__burger-cross`

But I don't really know how to handle the nested rules.

Any help on sass-lint and regex is very welcome.

Comment: Do you assume everybody knows what "BEMified kebab-case" is? A link reference here and there could not hurt.

Comment: [`^([a-zA-Z]+|__[a-z]+)((?:__|-|--|)[a-zA-Z]+)*(__|--)?`](https://regex101.com/r/SsVde6/3) is this what you want?

Comment: @wp78de you are right!

Comment: @wp78de I tried your suggestion, but I don't want all the PascalCase after the first word:
In the meantime I came up with this:
https://regex101.com/r/PBNJvx/3

It works in almost all cases, unfortunately it also includes some which we don't want to allow. Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I wanted was

> I would like to evaluate nested BEM selectors in my scss files as well:

My regex was actually already highlighting all the wanted cases and the not wanted were not matched. 
The problem was, that the linter cannot lint nested BEM selectors. :(.
Read about it here:
https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/issues/339#issuecomment-72404341

So not much we can do here.